# Как сохранить запись как шаблон на Вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны

[image: Скрин настройка записи]

Я хочу сохранить запись как шаблон. Но кнопка сохранения не активна. Что мне делать? Тема consulting child

Comment: Написать его название?

Comment: Кнопка не активна. В других темах у меня получалось сохранить. Здесь кнопка не работает. Не важно название. Важно, что не получается сохранить.

Comment: Или вы про какое-то другое название спрашиваете?

Comment: Ну по идее там где у Вас поле с плейсхолдером "Название шаблона", нужно придумать и ввести ему какое-то название или после ввода кнопка сохранения тоже не активна?

Comment: Вот именно, что не активна

Comment: Это в консоли меняется? Чтобы кнопка снова стала активной?

Comment: Нет. По-умолчанию это работает таким образом, что она становится активна когда Вы вводите название в поле. В Вашем же случае понятия не имею почему она даже после ввода названия не активна, по скриншоту тяжело дать какой-то ответ. Ну можете конечно попробовать поискать через инспектор кода сам атрибут на кнопке и удалить его, но проблемы в целом это не решит. Так как это премиум тема, можете обратиться к разработчикам темы, там должна быть служба поддержки.

Comment: благодарю. я нашла решение. просто буду дублировать нужную запись)